# What does the "registered" field in Erlang OTP app files do?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

In Chapter 23 of Joe Armstrong's Programming Erlang book, there is a file called sellaprime.app with these contents:

```
%% This is the application resource file (.app file) for the 'base'
%% application.
{application, sellaprime,
 [{description, "The Prime Number Shop"},
  {vsn, "1.0"},
  {modules, [sellaprime_app, sellaprime_supervisor, area_server,
         prime_server, lib_lin, lib_primes, my_alarm_handler]},
  {registered,[area_server, prime_server, sellaprime_super]},
  {applications, [kernel,stdlib]},
  {mod, {sellaprime_app,[]}},
  {start_phases, []}
 ]}.
```

It generally makes sense, except for `sellaprime_super` in the `registered` list. I can't find that anywhere else. It seems like it should be `sellaprime_supervisor`. Also, no error comes up if I add a completely made up name to the `registered` list and call `application:start(sellaprime).` So, what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just for detecting name clashes between applications by [systools](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/systools.html) when you build a release. Here is documentation of [application resource file](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#id73836).

Comment: So it doesn't matter if its contents are wrong, just as long as no clashes occur. Got it.

Comment: That's right. You will eventually get runtime error (or some weird behaviour of applications) instead of systool error.